# Getting NppExec to understand path of the current file in Notepad++  (for Python scripts)

Tags: python, notepad++, nppexec

Using windows for the first time in quite awhile and have picked up notepad++ and am using the nppexec plugin to run python scripts. However, I noticed that notepad++ doesn't pick up the directory that my script is saved in. For example, I place "script.py" in 'My Documents' however os.getcwd() prints "Program Files \ Notepad++"

Does anyone know how to change this behavior? Not exactly used to it in Mac.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notepad++ >nppexec >follow $(current directory)

Comment: This is too easy, you must be a wizard.

Answer (score 2):

You could put something like this at the beginning of your script:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll be using it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem ideal for long-term.